# Draw a line with gradually increasing width

Tags: android

How can I draw a line on canvas which starts with a width of for example 2dp and ends with 10dp? I can't find a function for this. Would drawing a 10dp line and then clipping it work ?

Comment: You want something like this http://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3229055/Step-6.jpg . right?

Comment: Yes i need to lines like that one

Comment: do you have any code. please paste what you have tried to. This will be good starting point for us too.